# How can I use this Cholesky decomposition algorithm on this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, cholesky-decomposition

In [this course](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/07%3A_Spectral_Theory/7.04%3A_Orthogonality), the authors introduce a method for Cholesky decomposition of matrix $A$, based on row reduction:

---

> **Procedure 7.4.1: Finding the Cholesky Factorization**
>
> 1. Using only type 3 elementary row operations (multiples of rows added to other rows) put A in upper triangular form. Call this matrix $\hat U$. Then $\hat U$ has positive entries on the main diagonal.
> 2. Divide each row of $\hat U$ by the square root of the diagonal entry in that row. The result is the matrix $U$.
>
> **Example**:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
>  9 & -6 & 3 \\
>  -6 & 5 & -3 \\
>  3 & -3 & 6 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \rightarrow
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  9 & -6 & 3 \\
>  0 & 1 & -1 \\
>  0 & -1 & 5 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \rightarrow
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  9 & -6 & 3 \\
>  0 & 1 & -1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 4 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

---

- I wasn't able to find this algorithm on other sites, which seems strange,
- I don't understand how this algorithm is used on the example provided.

For example, which row operations (of type 3) can change the second row from $[-6, 5, -3]$ to $[0, 1, -1]$? Adding 2xR3 to R2 gives $[0, -1, 9]$ and from there I cannot figure out how this can be improved.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When creating upper triangle, you only use the row(s) above the one you’re working with. In this case add $2/3$ of the first row to the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in the algorithm: the allowed operations must be adding a multiple of a row to other rows ***below*** it. Only these elementary operations are implemented by lower triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal, and in this case we will indeed obtain the $U$ part of $LU$ decomposition, from which it is possible to get Cholesky decomposition.

In the example we add $\frac23$ of the first row to the second and subtract $\frac13$ of the first row from the third.

Comment: Thanks for the complementary explanations.